# LINQ statement optimization

Tags: c#, linq

```
var person = People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter);
SelectedPerson = person ?? DefaultPerson
```

Could this be written in one statement?
Measing can I provide the default element that `SingleOrDefault` returns?

I am looking for someting like this (the second argument is the default element I provide).

```
var person = People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter, DefaultPerson);
```

The solution should also work for value types (ints, doubles, enums, structs, ...).

Comment: what about `SelectedPerson = People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter)??DefaultPerson`? it should work.

Comment: How will you distinguish between a "valid" 0 or a "default" 0 for `ints`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use DefaultIfEmpty():

```
var person = People.Where(p => p.Name == parameter).DefaultIfEmpty(DefaultPerson).Single();
```

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` still returns `IEnumerable` so another `First()` is necessary. But yes, that's what I was looking for! Thx

Comment: @WolfgangZiegler:  another _Single()_ would be necessary to provide the same behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an extension:

```
public static T SingleOrDefault<T>
    (this IEnumerable<T> list, T defaultValue) 
    where T : class
{
    return list.SingleOrDefault() ?? defaultValue;
}
```

and then call it with:

```
var person = People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter, DefaultPerson);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little obvious, but would this work for you?

```
var person = People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter) ?? DefaultPerson;
```

Comment: I am looking for a more generic solution, that would also work with value types (int, double, structs, ...). Sorry for the bad example ...

Answer (score -1):

You can create an extension method, which give you an instance if nothing will be found:

```
public static class PersonExtensionMethod
{
    public static T SingleOrInstance<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> precate)
    {
        var person = source.SingleOrDefault(precate);

        if (person == null)
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        return person;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
 List<Person> persons = new List<Person> { new Person(), new Person(), new Person() };

 var foundPerson = persons.SingleOrInstance<Person>(p => p.Name == "bla");
```